# How to apply a decorator without using it as a decorator?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to test a decorated class method:

```
class S3Store(object):
    @retry(exceptions=Exception, delay=1, tries=5, backoff=2)
    def delete(self, dest_id):
        return self._delete(dest_id=dest_id)

    def _delete(self, dest_id):
        bucket = self.conn.get_bucket(get_bucket_from_s3_uri(dest_id))
        key = Key(bucket, get_key_from_s3_uri(dest_id))
        key.delete()
```

I've mocked and tested `_delete` and now I want to test the retry logic.

I can't just test `delete()` directly because `Key` won't be mocked. So what I was hoping to do was something like the following:

```
decorated_fn = retry.retry_decorator(storage_backend._delete, delay=0.00001)
storage_backend.delete = decorated_fn
storage_backend.delete(...) ...         # add assertions, etc.
```

This doesn't work. I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'retry_decorator'
```

I think the problem is that the [`retry` decorator](https://github.com/invl/retry/blob/master/retry/__init__.py) is itself decorated.

How can I test the retry logic on my `delete()` method so its internal objects can be mocked, and so the delay timeout is very low?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not test the retry decorator at the delete function, but with a test function, that tests the retry decorator.

```
def test_retry(self):
    @retry(exceptions=ValueError, delay=1, tries=5, backoff=2)
    def test_raise_wrong_exception():
        raise AssertionError()
    self.assertRaises(AssertionError, test_raise_wrong_exception)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A decorator is a function that takes a function as argument, and returns a decorated version.

### Background

Your case is confusing, because it contains a lot of nesting. Let's first refresh the syntax of decorators:

When we write:

```
@decorator
def fun():
    pass
```

This is equivalent to:

```
def fun():
    pass
fun = decorator(fun)
```

In your example, the `retry` function is not actually the decorator, but is creating the decorator:

```
@decorator_factory(...)
def fun():
    pass
```

Is equivalent to:

```
def fun():
    pass
decorator = decorator_factory(...)
fun = decorator(fun)
```

### Solution

It should now be obvious that you want:

```
decorator = retry(delay=0.00001)
decorated_fn = decorator(storage_backend._delete)
```

### Other

If we look at the source, it looks like `retry_decorator` is not actually a decorator: it returns results of `f`, rather than a new function with augmented behavior:

```
@decorator
def retry_decorator(f, *args, **kwargs):
    for i in count():
        try:
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except exceptions, e:
        if i >= tries:
        raise
        round_delay = delay * backoff ** i
    log.warning('%s, retrying in %s seconds...', e, round_delay)
        time.sleep(round_delay)
```

But the `@decorator` converts `retry_decorator` to an actual decorator [see here](http://micheles.googlecode.com/hg/decorator/documentation.html#decorator-is-a-decorator).